# How to Populate Google Sheet Cell with Selected Value from HTML UI?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created an HTML UI from a Google Sheet file I am working with.  The UI pulls a list of vendors from my Vendor Database tab, allowing a user to select which vendor they'd like to place an order with from the HTML UI.  Upon click of the Save button in the HTML UI, though, I'd like the file to populate cell B12 of the POTemplate tab with the user's selection, but am unsure how to do this.  Right now, I have taken the following steps to make this happen, but with limited success:

APPS SCRIPT

This populates the HTML drop down list with vendor names from our Vendor Database tab in the active file:

```
function getVendors() {
  var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = active.getSheetByName("Vendor Database");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow); 
  var data    = myRange.getValues();
  var optionsHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=1) {
    optionsHTML += '<option>' + data[i][0] + '</option>';
  };
  return optionsHTML;
```

This attempts to grab the vendor selected in the HTML UI and populate the preferred cell in our POTemplate tab, B12:

```
  function save(formObj) {
    var vendor = formObj.vendor;
    var app = SpreadsheetApp;
    var orderSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("POTemplate");
     orderSheet.getRange(B12).setValue(vendor);
}
```

HTML Code

```
<html>
<head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
    <div>
      <select id="vendor">
        <?!= getVendors(); ?>
      </select>    
      <select>
        <?!= getATTN(); ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
    <input type="button" value="Save PO" class="button button2" 
onClick="google.script.run.save(this.parentNode)" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You say "limited success" - what is working, and what is not? Be clear and specific. Are there error messages in Apps Script? In the HTML browser console?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, Tehhowch.  The breakdown is occurring when the chosen vendor is selected by the user in the HTML UI and the 'onClick' function is called to execute.  My guess is the error is in the save() function language as nothing happens when I ask the code to populate cell 'B12' in the POTemplate tab of my file with the selected option from the HTML UI.  Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: Sorry... no error messages.  Just not populating cell B12, as directed.

Comment: Have you verified that your functions are all being called, by logging to the browser console in HTML and to Stackdriver in your apps script code? Have you tried using a local function to call the `.run` method, rather than directly calling it via oncl onclick?

Comment: When I run the save() function by itself after subsituting in a hard-coded sample vendor name, B12 populates.  The breakdown, when I run the code as a whole, looks to be that apps script is not pulling the HTML UI selection before working to set the value of B12.

Comment: Is it your intent that the button is not in the form? Have you verified what `this.parentNode` evaluates to, by logging it to the browser console before passing it to the `.run` method? Please edit your question to include the output from logging this very important quantity, and others (such as the input received by your `save()` method).

Comment: I was able to resolve.  Thanks for your help, Tehhowch!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

code.gs:

```
function getSelectOptions() {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Vender Database').getDataRange().getValues();
  var options = [];
  //the loop skips the first line
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    options.push(data[i][0]);
  }
  return options;
}
//for the webapp
function doGet()
{
  var output=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test');
  return output.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
//for a dialog
function showDialog(){
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Get Options');
}
```

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateSelect)
          .getSelectOptions();//this updates the select options everytime you load the page.
      });

     function updateSelect(vA){
      var select = document.getElementById("sel1");
      select.options.length = 0; 
      for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
      {
        select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
      }
    }  
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <select id="sel1"></select>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**Saving the Selected Value in a Sheet**

additional gs:

```
function savSelected(selected){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("POTemplate").getRange('B12').setValue(selected);
}
```

additional script function:

```
function savSelect(){
      var selected=$('#sel1').val();
      google.script.run.savSelected(selected);
    }
```

additional html:

```
<select id="sel1" onChange="savSelect();"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks,  Cooper.  I am now looking for a how to on populating a cell (B12) within the POTemplate tab of my Google Sheets file with the option selected in the HTML UI.  I have since gotten the HTML drop down to populate with the options from my Vendor Database tab.  This is my next step, but I am having limited success getting the selected value over to my target tab/cell.

Comment: @EricK. checkout the latest change to the answer

Comment: Cooper - this seems to drift pretty far from my existing code, though I trust it works equally as good, if not better.  I am not 100% comfortable abandoning the code I've written, though.  Is it possible for you to look again at what I've written to see where mine can be improved to deliver the desired outcome?  Sorry for this!

Answer (score 0):

In your `save()` function, you need to surround "B12" in quotes.

```
function save(formObj) {
  var vendor = formObj.vendor;
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var orderSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("POTemplate");
  orderSheet.getRange("B12").setValue(vendor);
}
```

In your HTML, you should not surround the `google.script.run` in quotes. Moreover, create a new function to make your life easier. You can modify the `submitFormData()` function in the HTML to include any other data that you might need to return.

```
<input type="button" value="Save PO" class="button button2" 
onClick=submitFormData() />
<script>
  function submitFormData() {
    var vendor = document.getElementById("vendor").value;
    var formObj = {};
    formObj["vendor"] = vendor;
    google.script.run.save(formObj);
  }
</script>
```

(The `getATTN()` function wasn't provided, so I removed that from the HTML when testing this.)