# Data extract from the Google spreadsheet to use in HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have 300 plus employee data. I want to collect their mobile number details. For collection of mobile number data I have made HTML page which collecting the details like Employee number , Employee Name and Mobile number.
Here I want that on input of the employee ID , name of the employee will auto populate in the page. For which I have made HTML / JavaScript code shown below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Data Collecction for</title>
</head>

<body>

<form id="my-form">

<script>

function MyFun() {


var response1 = document.getElementById('N1').value;

 if (response1 == '') {document.getElementById("N2").value = ''; alert('Please enter your employee ID');}   
 
 else if (response1 == "100220") {document.getElementById("N2").value = 'William';}
 else if (response1 == "100221") {document.getElementById("N2").value = 'Lucas';}
 else if (response1 == "100222") {document.getElementById("N2").value = 'John';}

 else {document.getElementById("N2").value = ''; alert('Please enter correct employee ID');}             
            
}

</script>

  <label for="T1">Employee ID:</label><br><br>
  <input type="number" id="N1" onchange="validity.valid||(value='');MyFun()" ><br><br>

  <label for="T2">Employee Name:</label><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="N2" readonly required style="background-color:#E6E6FA"  size="50" ><br><br>


  <label for="T4">Mobile Number:</label><br><br>
  <input type="text" pattern="[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" id="N4" ><br><br>

  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" name="myButton">Submit</button></center>



</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here I have use javascript to populate name of employee. But here I required to change the code each time whenever employee database change. I want that "Employee name" should be extract from the Google Spreadsheet based on "Employee ID".  Sample Google spreadsheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lz8FSufGAj0bIj8PpDfxI0YOuuO2LW0bXEFX3VSOkD0/edit?usp=sharing).

I tried to search on internet but failed to do so. Can please help me so that once i update the Google SpreadSheet and then HTML page extract it and use in the form.

Comment: Please share image of your spreadsheet

Comment: I would use a `<select>` tag to hold all of the employee ids and then use the onChange event of the `<select>` tag to look up the rest of the employee data and load it into the form and once the mobile number is added you can submit the form and load the mobile number.

Comment: @Cooper can please share the code .

Comment: Why don't you try it first.  I've done it a lot of times.  What we would like to accomplish here is helping you to learn how to do it.

Comment: Here's an example of populating a select from a spreadsheet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49615546/how-to-populate-google-sheet-cell-with-selected-value-from-html-ui/49616175#49616175

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull data from google spreadsheet you can publish your spreadsheet as a web app and use it as a REST API, you can read more about that here.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

An example of that you want to do would be the following:

```
function doGet(e) {

    var employee_id = e.parameter.employee_id;

    var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:B').getValues();

    var find = values.find((row) => row[0] === employee_id);

    var result = {name: find ? find[1]:'Not found'};

    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(params);

}
```

Comment: Web App giving the error "TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined (line 9, file "Code")". Also I does not know how to use it with HTML. Please help.

Comment: Sorry I just updated the example, when you deploy the webapp google is going to give you an url to use it, with that you can do a fetch request in your HTML code and when the onchange event is fired you can get the data and that is